# MySql back-up dump file not restored into MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql

I have created MySQL backup dump file using Java code. While restoring dump file into MySQL Administrator it is giving MySQL error:

> The selected file was generated by `mysqldump` and cannot be restored by this application.

Below my code for creating MySQL dump file:

```
public class MysqlBackup  {
    public boolean backupDataWithDatabase(String dumpExePath, String host, String port, String user, String password, String database, String backupPath) {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            Process p = null;                
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Date date = new Date();               
            String filepath = "backup(with_DB)-" + database + "-" + host + "-(" + dateFormat.format(date) + ").sql";               
            String batchCommand = "";              
            if (password != "") {                   
                batchCommand = dumpExePath + " -h " + host + " --port " + port + " -u " + user + "< --password=" + password + " --add-drop-database -B " + database + " -r \"" + backupPath + "" + filepath + "\"";                   
            } else {                  
                batchCommand = dumpExePath + " -h " + host + " --port " + port + " -u " + user + " --add-drop-database -B " + database + " -r \"" + backupPath + "" + filepath + "\"";
                             }

            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            p = runtime.exec(batchCommand);             
            int processComplete = p.waitFor();             
            if (processComplete == 0) {                   
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(backupPath + "" + filepath);                 
                ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:\\desktop13\\serverdb.zip"));                   
                out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("serverdb.sql"));                 
                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                int count;
                while ((count = in.read(b)) > 0) {                     
                    out.write(b, 0, count);
                }
                out.close();
                in.close();                  
                status = true;                   
            } else {
                status = false;                 
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
           MysqlBackup b = new MysqlBackup();
        b.backupDataWithDatabase("D:\\xampp1\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump.exe", "localhost", "3306", "root", "", "serverdb", "D:\\desktop13");
    }
    }
```

Comment: The problem doesn't lie in how you create the dump, but with how you restore it. What do you do to get the error? A search for the error might also be a good idea

Comment: @martin i exported database backup using command prompt i got the dump file that same file i am importing into using mysql tool it is  giving that error.

Comment: yes, but how are you importing the dump? What do you do in MySQL Administrator to get that error? Normally the output is imported using the mysql command.

Comment: ya k k but i exported through command prompt and i want to import that file using mysql administrator tool while importing i am getting that error